# Property: Get: Set: Serialize to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a class defined that auto increments a property in its get method. I am trying to serialize this object to an XML and the auto-incremented property is not being printed. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        
        MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
        string transactionXML = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Current ID: " + _myClass.ID);
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
                System.IO.StringWriter _sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(_sw);
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, _myClass);
                transactionXML = _sw.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("XML:\n" + transactionXML);
    }
    
     [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        long last_id = 0;
        public string ID{get { return System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref last_id ).ToString("D6"); }}

    }
}
```

When I try to run this, it runs with no errors, but does not print the ID in the XML.

Comment: You don't have a `set` accessor. XML serialization only considers read-write properties.

Comment: Side note: The `[Serializable]` attribute is has nothing to do with XML serialization. You can omit that unless you're also doing binary serialization.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How do I go about putting in a setter?

Comment: The whole design needs to be rethought. A `get` accessor shouldn't mutate the object, with the exception of lazy initialization. You need one class for dealing with the auto-incrementing ID logic, to give you control over when to increment, and a separate class for serialization, which has a read-write property (an auto-implemented property should suffice because it shouldn't contain the logic you have here).

Comment: [Adding a setter works](https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/ClassicFearlessAggregator#main.cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to extend you "MyClass" ID with a setter like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    long last_id = 0;
    public string ID { get { return System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref last_id).ToString("D6"); } set { } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Limitation of `XMLSerializer` - Properties without a setter can't be serialized.

But you can use `DataContractSerializer` to serialize private setter properties -

```
[DataMember]
public string Id
{
    get
    {
         return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    private set {}
}
```